# How is $\sin x < x < \tan x$ the same as $x \cos x < \sin x < x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How is $$\sin{x} < x < \tan{x} $$ the same as $$x \cos{x} < \sin{x} < x$$ when $x$ is $0 < x < \pi/2$?

Comment: Well, one of the inequalities $\sin x<x$ appear at both places. For the other one, use that $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$...

Comment: Ah! I see it, silly me, thanks a lot

Comment: Three answers and yet I'm the only one who's up-voted the question so far.  (I added my own answer and I probably wouldn't have done that after two answers had been posted if I hadn't thought I could make it somewhat simpler than the others.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sin x < x < \tan x
$$
$$
\sin x < \overbrace{x < \tan x}^A \qquad \qquad \overbrace{\sin x < x}^B < \tan x
$$
$$
\underbrace{\overbrace{x\cos x < \sin x}^A \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \overbrace{\sin x < x}^B}_\text{Now put these two together.}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the right part of the inequality given: $x \lt \tan(x)$.

Multiply $\cos(x)$ on both sides, and we get:

$$ x \cos(x) \lt \sin(x) $$

Combine this with the left part of the original inequality,

$$ x \cos{x} \lt \sin{x} \lt x $$

Comment: It might be helpful to add a note about reversing the implication, since the question asks to show these are "the same".

Answer (score 0):

Divide $x\sin x$ by the inequation and get

$$\frac{x\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}>\frac{x\sin(x)}x>\frac{x\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}.$$

Because of the division, the comparisons are reversed.